# Heroku JAVA | Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: java, heroku

I have a JAVA application which I'm trying to deploy to Heroku but I keep on encountering this issue.

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
```

I have added the following which is recognised in Heroku:

```
<web>java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Bot</web>
```

This is recognized but doesn't seem to help, my program uses JDA to control Discord and also downloads a JSON from URL. I tried setting the port to 5000 in resources/properties but that also had no effect. The program works fine for the first 90 seconds.

Comment: Are you deploying a website? No? -> In `Procfile` change `web` to `worker`

Comment: I tried changing it to worker but my program wouldn't start just with Heroku saying it has crashed with no extra information